# Android Splash Screen AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

Basically I have a loading splash screen which will be executed when button was clicked:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // Load the loading splash screen
            Intent loadingIntent = new Intent(context, LoadingScreen.class);
            context.startActivity(loadingIntent);
        }
    });
```

And in the LoadingScreen class:

```
public class LoadingScreen extends Activity{
//A ProgressDialog object  
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;  

/** Called when the activity is first created. */  
@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
{  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    //Initialize a LoadViewTask object and call the execute() method  
    new LoadViewTask().execute();         

}  

//To use the AsyncTask, it must be subclassed  
private class LoadViewTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>  
{  
    //Before running code in separate thread  
    @Override  
    protected void onPreExecute()  
    {  
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoadingScreen.this,"Getting routes...",  
                "Loading data, please wait...", false, false);  
    }  

    //The code to be executed in a background thread.  
    @Override  
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            //Get the current thread's token  
            synchronized (this)  
            {  
                //Initialize an integer (that will act as a counter) to zero  
                int counter = 0;  
                //While the counter is smaller than four  
                while(counter <= 4)  
                {  
                    //Wait 850 milliseconds  
                    this.wait(750);  
                    //Increment the counter  
                    counter++;  
                    //Set the current progress.  
                    //This value is going to be passed to the onProgressUpdate() method.  
                    publishProgress(counter*25);  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        catch (InterruptedException e)  
        {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  

    //Update the progress  
    @Override  
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)  
    {  
        //set the current progress of the progress dialog  
        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);  
    }  

    //after executing the code in the thread  
    @Override  
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)  
    {  
        finish();
        //close the progress dialog  
        progressDialog.dismiss();  
    }  
}
```

}

With these codes, the loading splash screen did came out. But I wonder is there any other way to show only the pop out dialogue for loading progress bar which on top on my previous screen?

Let's say my previous screen was event details. Then when user selected the button, only the dialogue box with loading progress bar will be shown instead of a new intent with a dialogue box.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            // Load the loading splash screen
            new LoadViewTask().execute();     

            ENeighbourhoodActivity.tvDirection.setText("");
            eventModel.setEventX(String.valueOf(eventModel.getEventX()));
            eventModel.setEventY(String.valueOf(eventModel.getEventY()));
            new GetEventDirectionAsyncTask(new GetEventDirectionAsyncTask.OnRoutineFinished() {
                public void onFinish() {
                    //Hide the callout and plot user location marker
                    ENeighbourhoodActivity.callout.hide();
                    EventController.getUserLocation(context);
                    getActivity().finish();
                }
            }).execute(eventModel);
        }
    });

public class GetRegisteredEventAsyncTask extends
    AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {
static EventController eventCtrl = new EventController();
public static ArrayList<Event> upcomingModel = new ArrayList<Event>();
public static ArrayList<Event> pastModel = new ArrayList<Event>();

public interface OnRoutineFinished { // interface
    void onFinish();
}

private OnRoutineFinished mCallbacks;

public GetRegisteredEventAsyncTask(OnRoutineFinished callback) {
    mCallbacks = callback;
}

public GetRegisteredEventAsyncTask() {
} // empty constructor to maintain compatibility

@Override
protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        upcomingModel = eventCtrl.getRegisteredUpcomingEvent(params[0]);
        pastModel = eventCtrl.getRegisteredPastEvent(params[0]);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
    if (mCallbacks != null)
        mCallbacks.onFinish(); // call interface on finish
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
}
}
```

Comment: Down voters mind to explain?

Comment: please check this [Link](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/02/ways-to-code-splash-screen-for-android.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `onClick()` method you could write something like:

```
new LoadViewTask().execute();
```

and the progress dialog will be shown in that page itself.

Comment: But by doing that, it will first shows the splash screen then followed by my AsyncTask method which took very long to load the data. Is there any ways to make both of them synchronized?

Comment: Intent loadingIntent = new Intent(context, LoadingScreen.class);
            context.startActivity(loadingIntent);   remove these lines from onClick(). Just call new LoadViewTask().execute(); in your onClick(). Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah I did. Can you help me check my edited portion? Because by doing this, it will first load the splash screen. Once finished loading, it will then execute the method in my AsyncTask. Is there any ways to make them both synchronized?

Answer (score 0):

what are you doing man, just call your AsyncTask not the intent

```
public void onClick(View v) 
    {
         new LoadViewTask().execute(); 
    }
});
```

do your intent in postExecute

```
 @Override  
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)  
{  
    finish();
    //close the progress dialog  
    progressDialog.dismiss();  
    //START YOUR ACTIVITY HERE
    Intent loadingIntent = new Intent(context, LoadingScreen.class);
    context.startActivity(loadingIntent);
}
```

Must read the documentation of [AsynTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Can you help me check my edited portion? Because by doing this, the splash screen will appear first then followed by my AsyncTask method. Is there any way so that while loading the splash screen, I am running the method in AsyncTask also?

Comment: Basically my methods inside GetRegisteredEventAsyncTask will took quite long to load the data so I am using splash loading screen. So what I am trying to do is, when user selected the button, it will load the splash screen and execute the methods inside GetRegisteredEventAsyncTask at the same time. By doing in the codes I provided above, it will first load the splash screen. Once finished loading, then execute the methods inside GetRegisteredEventAsyncTask.

Comment: so with this, my splash loading screen seems abit redundant